# Translate Augeas into Puppet speak Augeas

Tags: puppet, augeas

Using puppet's augeas capability I want to modify the config file:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Without puppet I've experimented using Augeas's "augtool" and found a couple of lines which seem to work:

```
augtool> set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Match[1]/Condition/User "bill","ben"   
augtool> set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Match/Settings/PasswordAuthentication "no" 
augtool> save
```

Although it seems to work OK, I don't really understand what purpose the [1] serves here.

I've tried without success to put those lines into Puppet:

```
augeas { "sshd_config":
  context => "/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config",
  changes => [
  'set Match[1]/Condition/User "bill","ben"',
  'set Settings/PasswordAuthentication "no"',
  ],     
}
```

It gives the error:
Error: /Stage[main]/Samipermissions/Augeas[sshd_config]: Could not evaluate: Saving failed, see debug

Running Puppet in debug mode tells me the same thing.

Does anybody know how this is meant to work ?

THANK YOU m0dlx.
Your answer has moved me past the error I was getting however I think I'm still a bit lost with the array of Matches. Using "augtool" I can do the following:

```
set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Match[1]/Condition/User "neil","nigel"
set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Match[1]/Settings/PasswordAuthentication "no" 
set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Match[2]/Condition/User "yvonne","yvette"
set /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config/Match[2]/Settings/PasswordAuthentication "yes"
```

in the config file this appears as:

```
Match User neil,nigel
  PasswordAuthentication no
Match User yvonne,yvette
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Which is perfect. I translated this to Puppet as:

```
  augeas { "sshd_config":
    context => "/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config",
    changes => [
      'set Match[1]/Condition/User "neil","nigel"',
      'set Match[1]/Settings/PasswordAuthentication "no"',
      'set Match[2]/Condition/User "yvonne","yvette"',
      'set Match[2]/Settings/PasswordAuthentication "yes"',
    ],
  }
```

But the result in the config file is quite different:

```
Match User neil
  PasswordAuthentication no
Match User yvonne
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although it seems to work OK, I don't really understand what purpose the [1] serves here.

The `[1]` is like accessing an array element, it indicates you want to access the first `Match` entry if there are multiple.

> 'set Settings/PasswordAuthentication "no"',

You've missed off the leading `Match/` that you had in the augtool test, this might cause the save failure from Puppet.

If you still have a problem, please include the full debug output from Puppet in the question.

Comment: Also, [augeasproviders_ssh](https://forge.puppet.com/herculesteam/augeasproviders_ssh) has an `sshd_config` provider that manages conditions pretty well: https://forge.puppet.com/herculesteam/augeasproviders_ssh#manage-entry-in-a-match-block

Comment: Thank you Raphink but I'm trying to get to grips with Augeas rather than use an imported module

Comment: Thank you m0dlx that was a great help, sadly it doesn't get me quite where I need to be. I've added to the question taking your help into account

Comment: Try removing the middle set of quotes from the names, e.g. `'set Match[1]/Condition/User "neil,nigel"',`

Comment: m0dlx  you are a star. Thank you very much . Between your answer and your comment you have helped me immensely, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer and later comment from m0dlx led me to the following which works perfectly:

```
  augeas { "sshd_config":
    context => "/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config",
    changes => [
      'set Match[1]/Condition/User "neil,nigel"',
      'set Match[1]/Settings/PasswordAuthentication "no"',
      'set Match[2]/Condition/User "yvonne,yvette"',
      'set Match[2]/Settings/PasswordAuthentication "yes"',
    ],
  }
```

Thank you m0dlx.